# Transform all buttons to jQuery UI Button Widget without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I've just got interested in jQuery UI Button widget. So in order to apply jQuery UI Button theme we have to do something like this:

```
$("input[type=button]").button();
```

But what if I would like to have all my buttons in whole site styled as jQuery UI Button widget. Do I always have to call **button()** (it will add some startup performance overhead, and as I'm supporting IE7...), or is there a way to generate markup (using server-side ASP .NET Web Forms) that is already jQuery UI Button ready?

Comment: You can copy the same CSS styles applied to jQuery buttons but...do you really think it'll impact performance in any way to use JavaScript for this task???

Comment: I won't impact but I have a few pages with huge javascript chunks and these pages already load quite long (I want to avoid buttons "transformation flickering" effect)... So I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the method to create the button.

You can add the styles for the button my manually adding all of the classes, however; you loose the mouse-over functionality.

You really don't gain much by not calling `.button`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKH9x/)

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" name="test" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">test</span>
</button>​
```